# Alternative to .map in jsx for iterating?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, jsx

I'm using this in my jsx:

```
 {item.result && item.result.length
                  ? item.result.map((sale, i) => (sale.month === 1 ? <span key={i}>{sale.itemCount}</span> : 0))
                  : 0}
```

I am trying to return either sale.itemCount if it exists, & sale.month = 1. Or, return just the one 0.

Due to the affect of map when a 0 should be displayed it is displaying the number of 0's that map has iterartions e.g. 000

How can I display just one 0 when either the result array has no content or the matching sale.month doesn't exist in the result array? The code needs to also work in inline jsx.

I suspect that map is not the correct method to use.

Here are two examples of the result array:

```
result = [
    {
        "itemCount": 2,
        "month": 7
    },
    {
        "itemCount": -1,
        "month": 8
    },
    {
        "itemCount": 0,
        "month": 9
    }
]
```

```
result = []
```

For a better understanding the full code can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/darrylmorley/bxtne1jL/)

---

I've tried taking this outside of the JSX and have this function:

```
const searchResultDec = (item) => {
    if (item.result.length === 0) {
      return <span>0</span>; // returns 0 as expected
    }
    if (item.result.length !== 0) {
      item.result.forEach((result) => {
        if (result.month !== 12) {
          return <span>0</span>; // does not return anything
        }
        if (result.month === 12) {
          console.log(result.itemCount); // returns 1 for three items
          return <span>{result.itemCount}</span>; // does not return anything
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

But, again I'm having issues displaying the expected results where I have noted 'does not return anything'.

I am trying to display the result like so:

```
<td>
    {searchResultDec(item)}
</td>
```

And an example result array:

```
const result = [
    {
        "itemCount": 1,
        "month": 8
    },
    {
        "itemCount": 1,
        "month": 12
    }
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are trying to achieve. I think we have an XY problem here. Please read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'll update my question.

Comment: So you want to display only one number and the number should be either the itemCount of January (month 1) or the number zero. Is that correct?

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, I'm running this for each month to display  a table of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good idea to split your problem into independent pieces and then put them together. You might want to look at and always try to honour the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle). If you do this you will write better code then 90% of the programmers out there. Unfortunately humans are good at mixing pieces together. :-)

That being said there is a logic in your code that tries to get the order count for a month. So it makes sense to create a separate function for this:

```js
const result = [
    {
        "itemCount": 2,
        "month": 7
    },
    {
        "itemCount": -1,
        "month": 8
    },
    {
        "itemCount": 0,
        "month": 9
    }
];

function getItemCountForMonth(orderSummary, month) {
    const monthOrder = orderSummary.find(o => o.month == month);
    return monthOrder ? monthOrder.itemCount : 0;
}

console.log(getItemCountForMonth(result, 7));
console.log(getItemCountForMonth(result, 8));
console.log(getItemCountForMonth(result, 9));
console.log(getItemCountForMonth(result, 10));
```

Now you should be able to call this function in your JSX as follows:

```html
<td>
    {getItemCountForMonth(result, 1)}
</td>
<td>
    {getItemCountForMonth(result, 2)}
</td>
<td>
    {getItemCountForMonth(result, 3)}
</td>
```

And so on... Maybe even create a loop for this.

Array.map is not what you need as it is going to create a new array with one entry for each of the entries in your original array. That's why it is called "map". It maps one entry to a new entry.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll try to keep your advice in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Just return `null` instead of 0.

```
{
  item.result && item.result.length
    ? item.result.map((sale, i) =>
        sale.month === 1 ? (
          <span key={i}>{sale.itemCount}</span>
        ) : null,
      )
    : null
}
```

Comment: I need one 0 though, I'll edit my question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{item?.result?.length
                  ? item.result.map((sale, i) => 
sale.month === 1? <span key={i}>{sale.itemCount}</span> :0))
                  : 0}
```

Comment: That's probably a better way oft setting my condition but no 0 is displayed if there is no sale.itemCount.